# Groovy configslurper directly into object

Tags: groovy

I have a groovy configuration file that I'm parsing with ConfigSlurper. This gives me a ConfigObject that functions like a map.

```
String x = "foo"
String y = "bar"
```

I also have an object that exactly matches the Configuration file

```
public class Example{
String x
String y
}
```

Now I could write code to load the Config file I just slurped into this object, but does Groovy have an automatic way of doing it? Like a

```
`Example e = ConfigObject.parseIntoObject(Example.class);`
```

Comment: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/gapi/groovy/util/ConfigObject.html - does not seem to have such method.

Comment: Try to use ObjectGraphBuilder as in http://mrhaki.blogspot.ru/2009/09/groovy-goodness-building-object-graphs.html

Comment: You can call constructor of the Example class with the map that you got from ConfigSlurper `new Example(configMap)` and groovy will match fields of the class with the map entries.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way, for example in your config file

```
conf {
    example = new Example(
                  x: "foo",
                  y: "bar"
              )
}
```

or

```
conf {
      example = {
          x: "foo",
          y: "bar"
      } as Example
}
```

and read this

```
Example e = (Example) new ConfigSlurper().parse(new URL("file:///...path").conf
```